# Can I import dxf to create footprint in Altium?

Tags: altium

I know Altium allows importing dxf as board outline. Just wondering if we can somehow import it to create a footprint.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it in Altium Designer 22, assuming it is the same in Altium Designer 23, yes, you can import dxfs in the same manner as you do for the board outline.

Go to File -> Import -> AutoCAD -> DXF/DWG

https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/edaimporter-dlg-setupdialogimport-from-autocad-pcb-ad?version=22